# How do I order the parts of a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

So I'm having some trouble with these constructs.

> "By listening I bad accept the information"

Phonetically it doesn't sound right to me. I'm more in favor of

> "I'm bad at accepting the information"

But it is also possible to change the order of the sentence to

> "I accept the information bad (or badly), by listening."

Comment: Welcome! You're right not to trust the sound of the first one; it has many problems. I'm still having a little trouble, but I think the meaning that you want to communicate is that you have trouble getting information by listening? If so, you might want a different word besides "accept," since that means "agree to take in"; maybe "receive" or another word. But that's not the main point of your question, which is about word order.

Comment: idiom: to be bad at something or at doing something.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of responses:

Word order is off, but mainly the words themselves aren't really the best fit for your intended meaning.

I totally know what you're getting at, I'm the same way. Some ways I would describe my situation:

> I don't take in verbal information well.

> I don't absorb verbal information as easily as written information.

> I don't learn as much by listening as by reading.

The word 'accept' is more passive than you want I think.. so not the best meaning, also since it's passive, it fits differently in a sentence.

For word order, I'd suggest:

> I don't --verb-- by listening -well- or -very well-.

With the verb of your choice!